# Use Windows IDE to work with remote project on Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, ide, remote-debugging

I have a project kept in Git repository which is compiled on a huge Linux server. Currently, I connect using SSH to the Linux server, modify the files there and then run commands to compile and execute it.

Everything is done in command line which is really painfull and I would like to use an IDE on my Windows machine which can connect to the remote Linux machine using SSH. I just need the IDE for file modification, auto complete and similar stuff, function resolution etc. I don't need to be able to compile or debug through IDE.

Mounting using Samba or Sshfs is out of the question because it is too slow. I need speed. If I click save, it needs to be save. Autocomplete should work like locally, it should work as though the files are on my machine most of the time.

Can somebody recommend an IDE which this qualities and information on how to set it up.

Thanks

Comment: [windows ide over ssh to linux site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+ide+over+ssh+to+linux+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: I tried all the proposed solutions but everytime it is too slow. I am looking for something like a mirrored project or IDE on the Linux server accessed through web browser

Answer (score 0):

The best thing that worked out for me is [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/index.html). You have to have two copies of Unison, one on Windows client and one on remote Linux. You checkout the repository on the remote and then run Unison to synchronize the remote copy to your local. It connects to remote through ssh. Every time file is changed both locally or remotely, the other side gets updated instantly. Works well on slow connections.

You can then use your favorite IDE and work locally. The only quirt is that Unison must be same version and compiled with same Ocaml version (in my case Unison 2.48.4 with OCaml 4.0.4.). I had to compile it manually for Linux and for Windows I downloaded provided binary.